# Docker: how to use container to replace real smtp server?

Tags: docker, smtp

I built up my development environment using Docker containers, but currently all mails are sent by smtp server in my company, I cannot use it for testing. Is there a way that I can create a container that replaces the real smtp server? Do I need a DNS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, just setup your SMTP server to run in a docker container using a Dockerfile in the normal way. Then when you run the container make sure you open the SMTP port ...

docker run -p 25:25 --name yourSmtpDockerContainer yourSmtpDockerImage

now if the server the container is running in exposes port 25 ... then any traffic sent to the server's domain name will be sent to the container.

You may need to expose other SMTP ports too as required - cheers